# MYSQL UPDATE только пустых полей

Tags: php, mysqli, update

Есть таблица с почти сотней полей, и несколько десятков тысяч записей.
некоторое поля пустые, и в каждой строке они разные.
те поля которые заполнены меняться не должны, как и ид записи, так как привязки с других таблиц идут.

```
UPDATE table SET str1 = 'add_text1' WHERE str1 = '';
UPDATE table SET str2 = 'add_text2' WHERE str2 = '';
.....
UPDATE table SET strn = 'add_textn' WHERE strn = '';
```

решение конечно, но это огромное количество запросов.
задержки не критичны, но хотелось бы найти более красивое решение..

Comment: update table set str1 = case when str1 = '' then 'add_text1' else str1 end, str2 = ....

Comment: А вообще таблица с 100 полей обычно наводит на мысль, что ошибка на уровне проекта БД и она должна быть построена вообще иначе. Так же пустые значения, которые надо заменять, а не NULL вместо них так же наводит на мысль о том, что таблицей неправильно пользуются

Comment: таблица подгружается полностью и с ней работают, не видел смысла разносить на множество таблиц.  некоторые записи в поле могут уже отредактировать в момент работы, и удалить с нее данные. работаю с тем что есть, если заменить "" пустые поля на null то придется переписовать и часть кода, делать проверку если при редактировании убрали с нее текст то проверять если нет данных то присваивать полю null

Comment: А что вы на самом деле хотите для полей, в который пустые строки? Разовое заполнение каким-то значением по умолчанию? Тогда может быть стоит сделать ALTER TABLE для таких полей с указанием значения по умолчанию? Не зная структуры таблицы не очень точно можно  советовать.

В целом плохая история такие массовые преобразования, если даже делать в лоб - т.е. запускать UPDATE по отдельным полям, то я бы делал  это в цикле, пока есть изменения с ограничением LIMIT на UPDATE. Очень уж блокирующие у вас запросы, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Дмитрий, заполнять значением по умолчанию не вариант так как к этой таблице много что подвязано, есть уже готовая часть которая работает с этой таблицей, но по сути только на чтение, а переписовать чтоб сравнять что если там значение которою по умолчанию заполняется и на выводе его убирать не очень бы хотелось. нагрузка на базу меня не смущает, с базой работает 2 человека, может в день 1-2 раза.  может в далекой перспективе будет работать 3-4 челвоека, по 5 раз на день думаю что максимум.. и только один человек может с базой делать манипуляции.  лучшее враг хорошему...